# Making a faithful representation of a single Russian letter

Tags: russian

There is a paper I am citing that has an author with the name shown in the image below.
[image]

The default citation provided by the search engine I was using suggest `{\v i}`, which shows as the following in my paper:

[image]

I am wondering (since I don't now Russian) if this is even a faithful representation of the corresponding letter in Russian.  Also, I am wondering if `{\v i}` is the most accurate way to represent this letter in LaTeX.

This is the only Russian letter I need to represent in my document, so I don't have a need to include Russian language packages or similar things if it can be avoided.

Comment: @nordev, thanks for showing me that.  Now, I would like someone to confirm that `\u{\i}` is the correct Russian letter.

Comment: not a check, but a breve (rounded) over an undotted "i".  the english "translation" is "short i".  `\u{\i}`, but see duplicate for additional information.

Comment: It's definitely `\u{\i}`. I've noticed that bibliography search system tend to use the “háček” (`\v{\i}` or, even worse, `\v i`), but it's wrong as ǐ is used only in romanization of Chinese, as far as I know.

Comment: @egreg If that's any consolation, others use breves instead of háčeks in languages such as Czech and  Croatian ;-)